# How ASP.NET upload data and create Excel sheet?

Tags: asp.net

I created asp.net web application.i can't add Excel sheet upload way. this is my code

```
          protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
                using(SqlConnection con =new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select* from  employees", con);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);

                    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                    GridView1.DataBind();

                }

            }
        }

        protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Employees.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
            StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmlTextwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringwriter);

            GridView1.RenderControl(htmlTextwriter);
            Response.Write(stringwriter.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any "uploading" here; you're trying to stream the results of a query back to the browser as Excel. Problem is, the GridView doesn't render content in Excel native format.

If your data is relatively simple, look at rendering it as ContentType *text/csv* instead; there will be a million examples on the web of how to do this. Excel can read CSV which might be good enough for your scenario.